# Onreadystatechange - event or event handler?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Most docs say that `onreadystatechange` is an *event*. However, the JavaScript standard is to prefix *event handler* methods with 'On'. I'd still say that `onreadystatechange` is an event handler, because we assign an event handler method to it. Am I right? I mean, it is an event, but it shouldn't be prefixed with 'on'.

I'd say the naming conventions regarding events are very inconsistent across the most popular languages. For example in C# methods starting with 'On' are methods invoking the event. On the other hand, in Android an `OnClick` is an event invoked by clicking a button.

Comment: It is triggered when the browser fires the [readystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/readystatechange) event. Not much different when the index of a select changes or text in a textbox changes. So `onreadystatechange` is a property

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's primarily opinion based and depends on how strong you are following the naming conventions. But yeah, it makes sense that if you read `on`  at the beginning of a function name, means that the function will be executed `on` the given event (which should be the rest of the functions name). You could say the same about `onbeforeunload`.

But, `onreadystatechange` and `onbeforeunload` are actually event handlers, for example, if you want to attach an event handler with `jquery`, you have to do `$(window).on('beforeunload')`, so the event name is `beforeunload` and the `on` prefix is not there, but in the jquery `on` method.

Comment: So the following statement is wrong. MS, please... 'All elements expose an onreadystatechange event.' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536957(v=vs.85).aspx